# How to Stop a Mulesoft flow using a connector in Anypoint Studio

Tags: json, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Is there a connector to stop the Mulesoft flow after a certain point? Let's say I have a request connector in the flow and I want to stop the flow soon after that connector is executed

Comment: Are you using Mule3 or mule4?

Comment: @AnuragSharma MULE4

Comment: so here best option is to create a custom connector, on this link https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-To-Stop-Or-Start-Flows-In-Mule-4-x-Programmatically you will get how to create a custom connector or if you can wait I can help you by creating by myself after 5-6 hours?

Comment: I've already gone through that link  not much of a help, when i go to search in exchange ans type scripting module. Do i need to create something in exchange?

Answer (score 0):

If its with regards **Mule4**,

-- https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-To-Stop-Or-Start-Flows-In-Mule-4-x-Programmatically

If its with regards **Mule3**,

-- https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-start-stop-a-flow-programmatically

Comment: when i go to search in exchange and search it with scripting module, nothing comes up

Comment: I searched and found it with no issues: https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.modules/mule-scripting-module/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try, wherever you want to stop your flow, give a "Raise Error" connector and give the Type as "ANY" and in the error handling section give an empty "on-error-continue" scope and in the on error continue properties uncheck "Log Exception" so that it doesn't log the error we raised.

Please find the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="d2c12e71-9f33-44f5-8515-616b1733d52a" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="stop-flow-wsFlow" doc:id="c668e851-46ec-459d-9252-109ec488c47e" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="e8e5a81d-97f7-4cda-8984-483ead08d376" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/stopflow"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger1" doc:id="b1e57888-acf6-41bb-af46-abc54acb8c5b" message='#["Logger1"]'/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger2" doc:id="02ba5ce3-69eb-4a8e-ae7a-063cd372ffa9" message='#["Logger2"]'/>
        <raise-error doc:name="Raise error" doc:id="872e5b03-64d4-499f-a77c-b69d12bfaf0c" type="ANY"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger3" doc:id="b54480ea-b89b-4b66-b2bd-152617860c4f" message='#["Logger3"]'/>
        <set-payload value='#["Hello World"]' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="04738f06-77d0-4953-a976-c14589718692" />
        <error-handler>
            <on-error-continue enableNotifications="true" logException="false" doc:name="On Error Continue" doc:id="87ac9f65-3456-4c00-b76c-c461acf0628c" />
        </error-handler>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Output would be:
[image]